# How to add filter yesterday, MTD(month to date) in d3.js line chart and change the chart on filter selection

Tags: d3.js

How to add filter yesterday, MTD(month to date) in d3.js line chart and change the chart on filter selection. As shown in attachment Yesterday, MTD, YTD, Custom are common filter for all 4 charts, how I can implement this in d3.js. So that on selection of filter chart should change accordingly.

Thanks!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgWN3.jpg)

Comment: What attachment are you referring to? Is it just me or it really sounds like excerpt from some homework question...

Comment: Kindly check the attachment now.

Comment: Your question is still too generic to be able to address it. You ask for complete implementation without specifying requirements and giving any data samples. If you want understand how to filter dataset and update rendering, follow any tutorial like [one of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=d3+update+exit+enter).